# d3 line disappears on data update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a graph where the data is changing on user update. There are 3 horizontal lines which marks thresholds moving along with the y scale. My code was running correctly, but now I noticed that one line just disappears. However it is only happening on the first data change. If I selected other data the 2 lines are not disappearing. I have no idea how this happened or where I changed anything with the line code...
I am using d3 v5.

This is my line data:

```
lineData = [
{ key: 'high',
  values: [
    {type: 'high', year: 1996, value: 1}, 
    {type: 'high', year: 2016, value: 1}
  ]},
{ key: 'medium',
  values: [
    {type: 'medium', year: 1996, value: 0.8}, 
    {type: 'medium', year: 2016, value: 0.8}
  ]},
{ key: 'low',
  values: [
    {type: 'low', year: 1996, value: 0.7}, 
    {type: 'low', year: 2016, value: 0.7}
]}
];
```

This is my code for plotting:

```
BarBackChart = function(_parentElement, _risk) {
this.parentElement = _parentElement;
this.risk = _risk;

this.initVis();
};

BarBackChart.prototype.initVis = function() {
let vis = this;
vis.margin = { left: 50, right: 20, top: 10, bottom: 50 };
vis.height = 450 - vis.margin.top - vis.margin.bottom;
vis.width = 625 - vis.margin.left - vis.margin.right;

//Init svg to draw in
vis.svg = d3.select(vis.parentElement)
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', vis.width + vis.margin.left + vis.margin.right)
  .attr('height', vis.height + vis.margin.top + vis.margin.bottom)
  .attr('class', 'plot-area');
vis.g = vis.svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${vis.margin.left}, ${vis.margin.top})`);

vis.t = 1000;

//Define plot titles
vis.g.append('text')
  .attr('x', vis.width/2)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text(vis.risk);

//Define scale types
vis.x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, vis.width])
  .padding(0.2);
vis.xLine = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range([0, vis.width], .09);

vis.y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([vis.height, 0]);

//Define axis 
vis.xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(vis.x);
vis.yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(vis.y);

vis.xAxis = vis.g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${vis.height})`);

vis.yAxis = vis.g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y-axis');

//Define lines
vis.line = d3.line()
  .x(d => vis.xLine(d.year))
  .y(d => vis.y(d.value));
//Set line colors
vis.lineColorScheme = ['#e79e27', '#044b87', '#04873f'];
vis.lineColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(vis.lineColorScheme)
  .domain(lineDataLong.map(d => d.key));

  vis.wrangleData();
}

BarBackChart.prototype.wrangleData = function() {
//BACK DATA
let vis = this;

for(let i = 0; i < nestedBackData.length; i++) {
  if(nestedBackData[i].key === vis.risk) {
    vis.datafiltered = nestedBackData[i].values;
  }
};
vis.minYear = Math.min(...([...new Set(vis.datafiltered.map(item => item.year))]));
vis.maxYear = Math.max(...([...new Set(vis.datafiltered.map(item => item.year))]));

vis.range = range(vis.minYear, vis.maxYear);
vis.datafiltered = fillYears(vis.datafiltered, vis.range, 0);

vis.updateVis();
}

BarBackChart.prototype.updateVis = function() {
let vis = this;

///////////////// AXIS /////////////////
//UPDATE SCALES
vis.x.domain(vis.datafiltered.map(d => d.year));
vis.y.domain([0, yMax]);

//UPDATE AXIS
vis.xAxis
  .transition().duration(vis.t)
  .call(vis.xAxisCall)
.selectAll('text')  
  .style('text-anchor', 'end')
  .attr('dx', '-.2em')
  .attr('dy', '.55em')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-45)');

vis.yTicks = vis.y.ticks();
vis.yTicks.push(0.7);    

vis.yAxis
  .transition().duration(vis.t)
  .call(vis.yAxisCall
    .tickValues(vis.yTicks))
    .attr('class', 'line');

///////////////// LINES /////////////////
  vis.lines = vis.g.selectAll('.line')
    .data(lineData)
  .attr('class', 'line');

vis.lines.exit()
  .remove();

vis.lines.enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('d', d => vis.line(d.values))
    .style('stroke', d => vis.lineColor(d.key))
    .style('stroke-width', '3px')   
    .style('stroke-opacity', .65)
  .merge(vis.lines)
    .transition().duration(1250)
    .attr('d', d => vis.line(d.values));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I added a .attr('class', 'line') to both the yAxis and the 3 lines.
I don't really understand why this leads to this behaviour so I'd much appreciate it if someone could give me (and everybody else) an explanation.